# MetaPost's undraw does not remove the whole border

Tags: diagrams, metapost, fill

I am running the example:

```
# := 0.5cm;

beginfig(1);
path tr;
tr := origin--(2#, 5#)--(8#, 5#)--(10#, 0#)--cycle;
color cl;
cl := 0.7(green + blue);
pen p;
p := pencircle scaled 2mm;

filldraw tr withcolor cl withpen p;
filldraw tr shifted (12#, 0#) withcolor cl withpen p;

undraw tr shifted (12#, 0#) withpen p;

endfig;
end;
```

I expected `undraw` to remove the *entire* border of a figure but it leaves a very thin border around it... What is wrong in my using of `undraw`?

Comment: To narrow it down: I can reproduce the problem even with `draw tr withcolor red withpen p;
draw tr withcolor white withpen p;`, so it does not seem to be caused by fill, shifted, or undraw.

Comment: Also it is persistent across viewers and both in postscript format and in pdf, so it is not a viewer or (downstream) rendering problem.

Comment: `undraw` is simply a macro defined as `draw ... withcolor background`... but if you look at the definitions of `draw` and `filldraw` you will see that they are quite different.  So there's a mismatch between your entirely reasonable expectation and the details of the implementation.

Comment: Did you try `unfilldraw` or is that not appropriate?

Comment: May I ask what are you actually trying to achieve with your drawing? (There may be a simpler way...)

Comment: @Thruston Yes, I've tried `unfilldraw` and it also left a tiny border. In fact, I am helping with MetaPost to another person and we try different MetaPost's elements and features to be able to work with this system. So I do not do a particularly practical thing. And when you `filldraw`'ed something and then `unfilldraw`'ed it, then you expect it would disappear.

Comment: @Thruston I supposed `filldraw` = `fill` (the interior) + `draw` (the border). So when you `filldraw`'ed a contour, you can either remove the whole figure with `unfilldraw`, or remove the only border with `undraw`, or remove the interior with `unfill` (and leave the border this way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought at first that the difficulty here was the way that `draw` and `filldraw` are defined, but after investigation I don't think that this is a MP problem. (See below).

First `undraw` is simply a macro defined in `plain.mp` as:

```
def undraw expr p = draw p withcolor background enddef;
```

So the issue is the different implementations of `draw` and `filldraw`.  These are also both macros defined in `plain.mp`:

If you pass a cyclic path `p` as an argument, then

- `draw` expands to `addto currentpicture doublepath p`

but

- `filldraw` expands to `addto currentpicture contour p`

so the difference visible in your view (and mine) is (apparently) the difference between the implementation of the *primitive* commands `doublepath` and `contour`.

☞ There's probably not much you can do about this except use a slightly larger pen to do your `undraw`.

### Further note

If I compile to `.eps` and examine the output, there is another clue

```
 0 0.7 0.7 setrgbcolor 0 5.66928 dtransform truncate idtransform setlinewidth pop
 [] 0 setdash 1 setlinejoin 10 setmiterlimit
newpath 0 0 moveto
28.34647 70.86617 lineto
113.38586 70.86617 lineto
141.73233 0 lineto
 closepath
gsave fill grestore stroke
newpath 170.0788 0 moveto
198.42526 70.86617 lineto
283.46466 70.86617 lineto
311.81113 0 lineto
 closepath
gsave fill grestore stroke
 1 1 1 setrgbcolor
newpath 170.0788 0 moveto
198.42526 70.86617 lineto
283.46466 70.86617 lineto
311.81113 0 lineto
 closepath stroke
showpage
```

You do not have to be a PostScript maven to see that the two paths at the end are identical and that one gets `gsave fill grestore stroke` to do the `filldraw` and the second (identical) copy gets `1 1 1 setrgbcolor stroke` to do the `undraw`.

At this point, I think we can conclude that the issue is at the PostScript level.  (Or possibly in your viewer or my printer or whatever else is trying to render the drawing).

Comment: I tried to `undraw` and `unfilldraw`with a slightly thicker pen -- it helped. So the matter is at the PostScript level... And I've learned I have to keep in mind the actual implementation of macros instead of 'common sense' expectations of their behavior...